# How can I redirect to a route depending on the outcome of an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am building a react app with redux. when a user submits a form, there are two possible outcomes: an error or success.

This is the action creator:

```
export const createSomething = (data) => {
return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    firestore.collection('data_s').add( {
        ...data,
    }).then((dts) =>{
        dispatch({
            type : 'CREATED_SUCCESS', dts
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
            type : 'CREATE_ERROR', err
        });
    })
}
```

};

and reducer:

```
const createSomethingReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATED_SUCCESS' : 
            console.log('created', action.data);
            return state;

        case 'CREATE_ERROR' :
            console.log('create error', action.err);
            return state;

        default : 
            return state
    }
}
```

The submit is done like so

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.createEmployee(this.state)
}
```

How would I direct to "/succcess" if the form is submitted successfully and "/error" if the form doesnt go through?

I have tried using

```
this.props.history.push('/app/dashboard')
```

But this redirects regardless of the outcome. Please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `.then` block in the createEmployee function return so that the promise chain continues and then in the handleSubmit function call

```
.then(() => this.props.history.push('/success'))
```

You can do the same with the catch block by throwing an error within the `catch` of the createEmployee function and then continuing with a catch in the handleSubmit function call

```
.catch(err => this.props.history.push('/error'))
```

The final function would look like this

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.createEmployee(this.state)
   .then(() => this.props.history.push('/success'))
   .catch(err => this.props.history.push('/error'))
}
```

Comment: When I add a .then, it gives me a cannot read property of undefined error.

Comment: Did you add a `return` in the original promise chains .then in createEmployee?

Comment: Yes I did. the new one is            return ([
            dispatch({
                type : 'CREATED_SUCCESS', dts,
            })
           ])